# How can I use id to show name of it? (phoenix framework)

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have 3 tables, foods, orders and order items. In foods table, it has food_id, name and price. Orders table has order_id and date. And in order_items table, it has order_id, food_id and quantity.

```
schema "orders" do 
has_many :order_items, Myapp.OrderItem

timestamps


schema "foods" do
field :name, :string
field :price, :integer

has_many :order_items, Myapp.OrderItem

timestamps



schema "order_items" do
field :quantity, :integer
belongs_to :order, Myapp.Order
belongs_to :food, Myapp.Food

timestamps
```

What I want to ask is that can I use food_id data in order_items table to show its price and name? If I can do this, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fetch an order with the food, you can preload using [Repo.preload/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/2) with a keyword list:

```
order = Repo.get(Order, 1) |> Repo.preload(order_items: :food)
```

You haven't specified what format you want to show the items in. To output them in an EEx template you can do something like:

```
<%= for order_item <- @order.order_items do %>
  <%= order_item.food.name %> (<%= order_item.food.price %>)
<% end %>
```